# How to insert number into a file name as a variable in databricks

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, databricks

I have 10 files created daily in my data lake with a file name like `0_2020_02_16_10_12_05.avro`, since 2020_02_16 is a date that the file is created and constant for the day but the minutes and seconds are not the same for all the files , I would like to replace the 2020_02_16 by a variable in my daily run. I have tried this but it does not work

```
val pfdtm = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)   
val fileDate =DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_MM_dd").format(pfdtm)



 Output:- fileDate=2020_02_16

val df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("adl://powerbi.azuredatalakestore.net/SD/eventhubspace/eventhub/0_${fileDate}_*_*_*.avro")
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Your `FileDate=2020_02_16` row looks incorrect. I assume it should be `val fileDate = "2020_02_16"`?

Comment: I have edited the question, it was a spelling error. the problem I am encountering is when I pass the file date output into my spark read path, Do you see any mistake when passing the variable into the path?